# Overloaded methods in REPL and in worksheet fail to compile

Tags: scala

The following code fails to compile in the REPL and in a worksheet:

```
def add(i: Int, j: Int): Int = i + j
def add(i: Int, j: Int, k: Int): Int = add(add(i, j), k)
```

With the following error:

```
Main.scala:63: not enough arguments for method add: (i: Int, j: Int, k: Int)Int.
Unspecified value parameter k.
def add(i: Int, j: Int, k: Int): Int = add(add(i, j), k)
                                          ^
Compilation Failed
```

However this code compiles just fine:

```
object Test {
  def add(i: Int, j: Int): Int = i + j
  def add(i: Int, j: Int, k: Int): Int = add(add(i, j), k)
}
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From REPL, each statement that you run goes in an inner scope so `add(i: Int, j: Int, k: Int)` with 3 parameters, shadows outer `add(i: Int, j: Int)`. That is why you get error from REPL.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to overload methods in the REPL, type them in `:paste` mode or wrap them in an object.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def add(i: Int, j: Int): Int = i + j
def add(i: Int, j: Int, k: Int): Int = add(add(i, j), k)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

add: (i: Int, j: Int)Int <and> (i: Int, j: Int, k: Int)Int
add: (i: Int, j: Int)Int <and> (i: Int, j: Int, k: Int)Int

scala> object Wrapper {
     |   def add(i: Int, j: Int): Int = i + j
     |   def add(i: Int, j: Int, k: Int): Int = add(add(i, j), k)
     | }
defined module Wrapper
```